# Completely stuck on install / service stop MYSQL

Tags: server, mysql

Recently, I got into the word of linux server (my own little powerful NAS, hehe) I tried to install mysql for my wordpress website. When installing, this happenend:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0TJWYH/06-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and there it went down hill.

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos# sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql_secure_installation: [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8mb4'.

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos# sudo service mysql start
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

I already tried these steps:

stopping or starting:

```
Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceFailed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
failed!
```

and When I start:

```
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceFailed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
failed!
```

f install:

```
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt -f install
[sudo] password for victoroos:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient21 libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-common php7.4-mysql
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
mysql-server-8.0
Suggested packages:
mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1481 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 131672 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
so quite a loop dy loop.

Thank for helping me out though, I'm really stuck

And when trying to stop it differently, I get:

victoroos@vicsserver:~$ service mysqld stop
Failed to stop mysqld.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.

victoroos@vicsserver:~$ su root
Password:
root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos# service mysqld stop
Failed to stop mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not loaded.
root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos#

victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-common mysql-server-8.0
[sudo] password for victoroos:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-server-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.25) but it is not going to be installed
mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ ^C
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken
E: Command line option --fix-broken is not understood in combination with the other options
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-common mysql-server*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-8.0' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql-server*'
Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.25) but it is not going to be installed
mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-common mysql-common*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql-common*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql-common*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.25) but it is not going to be installed
mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Of course, I tried the fix broken as it prints nicely :)

```
root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient21 libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-common php7.4-mysql
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1481 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 131672 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@vicsserver:/home/victoroos#
```

Conlusion is short, I need to be able to stop the service which is apparently running.. But I can't.. why? What steps should I take?
I hope I have given you enough to help me troubleshoot.

after srubbing:

```
victoroos@vicsserver:~$ sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client \
>                  mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.25) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-core-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Which NAS are you using? Some of them have hard requirements for MySQL 5.7 and upgrading to 8.x may have some unintended consequences. If this is a custom-build, which version of Ubuntu did you upgrade from? I can see from the `apt` logs that you're using Ubuntu Server 20.04.1, but this message only appears after an upgrade from an older system.

Comment: This is a fresh install (my own). and indeed Ubuntu server 20.04.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The following steps are generally to solve a "worst-case scenario", where there are processes running that you cannot identify the owner and you just need to put a stop to it. If this is a new Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation that you put on the machine yourself, then *something* that you installed also put MySQL (or MariaDB) on the machine. Before getting too crazy and killing processes, let's confirm the version of MySQL that is installed on your server:

```
$ mysql -V
```

If you see something like this next line, then perhaps you don't need to install MySQL at all:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Figure out where the installation came from, connect with `sudo` (eg. `sudo mysql`), and get the database ready for WordPress.

Otherwise ... let's scorch some earth.

---

#### Important

> The following set of instructions will do a couple of things:
>
> 1. Kill the currently-running MySQL process that does not respond to the standard `stop` command
> 2. Remove the currently installed version of MySQL
> 3. Install the Canonical release of MySQL Server

With the disclaimer out of the way, let's go hunting for MySQL:

1. Use `top` (or any other process-viewing tool) to identify the `PID` for MySQL:

   ```
   $ sudo top -p `pgrep mysql | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'`
   ```

   ***Note:** You could simply use* `sudo top`, *but the command above will limit the output to only MySQL, saving time.*

   You should get something that looks similar to this:

   ```
   top - 23:31:12 up 10 days, 22:02,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.04, 0.00
   Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
   %Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
   MiB Mem :   7725.7 total,    141.2 free,   3083.2 used,   4501.3 buff/cache
   MiB Swap:  31250.0 total,  31026.2 free,    223.8 used.   3577.0 avail Mem 

       PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    112265 mysql     20   0 3979708 693688  13032 S   0.3   8.8  50:35.45 mysqld
   ```
2. (This is horrible for so many reasons, but ...) Kill the process. If you do this from within `top`, press <kbd>K</kbd>, then the `PID` number. If you choose to kill the process from the command line, you can do it like this:

   ```
   $ sudo kill -9 112265
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change* `112265` *to whatever value you see for MySQL.*
3. Check which MySQL packages are currently installed on your system:

   ```
   $ sudo apt list "mysql*" --installed
   ```

   You will likely see something that looks like this, but with different version numbers:

   ```
   Listing... Done
   mysql-client-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-client-core-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-client/focal-security,focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed]
   mysql-common/focal,focal,now 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server-core-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server/focal-security,focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed]
   ```
4. Scrub MySQL from the system:

   ```
   $ sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client \
                    mysql-common "mysql-server-core-*" "mysql-client-core-*"
   ```

   ***Note:** You will get a long list of packages to be removed. Look at those packages. Make sure you understand what will be eliminated from the system. If you are comfortable with their removal, agree to the prompt and let* `apt` *do its thing.*
5. Ensure that `apt` is clean and up-to-date:

   ```
   $ sudo apt autoremove
   $ sudo apt autoclean
   $ sudo apt update
   ```
6. Re-install MySQL Server:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```
7. Run the secure installation procedure and set a good root password:

   ```
   $ sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```
8. When done, connect to MySQL and make sure everything is working:

   ```
   $ sudo mysql
   ```

   If you can sign in, then the server is working. You can also take a look at the existing databases (which should be limited to just system databases if this is really the first time MySQL has been installed).

   ```
   mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   | mysql              |
   | performance_schema |
   | sys                |
   +--------------------+
   4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
9. Create yourself an administrator account, because you cannot have WordPress (or any other tool) connect to MySQL as `root`:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'victoroos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'SuperSecretPassword!123';
   ```

   Also give that account all privileges so that it is *essentially* a `root` account:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'victoroos'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
10. Install WordPress ... or Apache & PHP if you haven't already done so.

Comment: wow, thank you for such an elebarote answer! This is probably me being a noob, but : sudo top -p `pgrep mysql | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'`
resutls in top: 
-p requires argument

And when I use sudo top > I don't see the msql command unfortunately

Comment: and added some info for the scrubbing part.